# How can i open a webpage that is in my C# program?

Tags: c#, html

I added an HTML Website `start.html` to my C# program.

`start.html` (including all the code) is in the resource folder.

I want to create a Button that opens `start.html`.

This is what I was using before:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Preview_prod/start.html"));
```

Is there a way to start  `start.html` directly, without accessing it through its Path?

Comment: Maybe.  The Net class Process has no environmental variable PATH set which is used to find applications.  So only choice is to put the start.html in same folder as c# application (in the bin folder).  So if you add the html to same folder as your cs source files.  You can then use menu Add Existing Item and browse for html file.  Then right click in Solution Explorer the html file and select the copy property which will copy the html to same folder as the c# exe.